# How to understand the "Announcer" badge (which link from where to where was clicked on 25 times?)

Tags: support, badges

I still don't know how to read the Announcer badge. [I've received it 34 times now](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=4561887) and each and every time I don't understand how to interpret it. My latest one says (with this link being clickable, same as when I see it):

> [You've earned the "Announcer" badge (Share a link to a post later visited by 25 unique IP addresses) for "Passing an array as an argument to a function in C".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c/51527502#51527502)

So, where did I link from where to where, and which link? Did I link TO my post in the link above ^^, or FROM this post? If TO this post, where is the link I pasted TO it? And if FROM this post, which link in the post is the one people have clicked on 25 times?

Answer (score 6):

There is a link with your user ID pointing **to** "Passing an array...", and that link was accessed by 25 unique different addresses.

The link with your ID is usually obtained by clicking "share" below a post.

Note that someone *could* in theory post a link somewhere with your user ID instead of theirs, simlply by substituting manually the ID part.

E.g.
[How to understand the "Announcer" badge (which link from where to where was clicked on 25 times?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415511/4561887).

The above link points to this question, as it was shared by you, simply because I substituted my user ID with yours. It's a not as likely scenario, but still possible.

About where the link is... we can't know. SO does not measure that for awarding the badge, simply that the link was accessed.

The link can be anywhere on the Web, on private instant messages, emails, etc.

You can try searching for the sharing link on different search engines. Google used to have a `link:` search operator, but I understand it doesn't work anymore. But searching for the link should give you some results (as long as the sharing places are public, which again, they may not always be).

Comment: Ok, do we know where this link is? And since the Announcer badge is awarded for me posting the link, then it must be that I posted a link somewhere else _to my own question_ which is "Passing an array...", right?

Comment: @GabrielStaples I did a Google search with your specific sharing URL `https://stackoverflow.com/a/51527502/4561887` and at least it's on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c/51527502#comment90023635_6567846), a code comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814330/2821954), and many scraper sites.

Comment: If I click on the link you posted, it changes from `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415511/4561887` to this expanded version `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-understand-the-announcer-badge-which-link-from-where-to-where-was-clic` at the top of the screen. Does that expanded version also get tracking? I see the number `415511` in it. Normally I use only the expanded URLs, not the short ones, since the expanded ones get auto-displayed as the name of the question, which is really convenient to not have to copy-paste that too.

Comment: The "expanded" version is the "real" URL. It's not tracked because it does not include your user ID. The "sharing" URL (the one you obtain by clicking "share"), is a "short URL" with your user ID appended. That's the reason it can be tracked and the badge can be awarded.

Comment: @yivi, interesting. I'm probably missing hundreds of opportunities for this badge then because I use almost exclusively the "real" URL, and even so, I've gotten the badge 34 times for the few rare cases I have used the short "Share" URL.

Comment: @GabrielStaples _because I use almost exclusively the "real" URL_: Possibly the same case with me, I'm yet to be awarded the _Announcer_ badge.